# Insert current page number inside `Exercise` environment

Tags: page-numbering, exercises

For a long question (set with `\usepackage{exercise}`) I'd like to print the current page number. But on the second page, it prints `1` (red number in the attached picture), while the automatic pagenumbering at the bottom of the page displays the correct `2`.

How to print the correct page number?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}

        \lipsum[1-8]

        \thepage

    \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very curious. Even after `Exercise` environment, the page number is incorrect.

Comment: @Sigur "expected" rather than "curious" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please give a hint, why this is expected?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, maybe *expected* for expert people, but for me, it is curious... :-) specially after quickly read the package file.

Comment: @Sigur see the answer below, the page number is only incremented as tex outputs pages and it always works ahead of the break to pick a good spot, for example if you have a long paragraph covering 10 pages, `\thepage` will have the same value throughout the text as it has the initial value as the para is set, only later the vertical list gets split into pages and the page number increased for each one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh great TeX-Wizard thanks a lot for enlightment of us mere mortals! Now it makes sense.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for explanation. Not so easy reason. My first impression was: *If the page number is correct on the footer, why not in the paragraph?*. Well, everyday we learn something new. Thanks.

Comment: @samcarter the (correct) answer below had already been posted which is why I left a short initial comment but see the longer comment above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\thepage` is never reliable, but the label/ref mechanism is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}

        \lipsum[1-8]

        \label{currentpg}\pageref{currentpg}

    \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Or, by means of a user command `\insertCurrPgNum` which maintains labels automatically. I am pretty sure, there is already a dedicated package available for this within the `oberdiek` bundle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{labelCnt}

\newcommand\insertCurrPgNum{%
  \stepcounter{labelCnt}%
  \label{pagelbl.\thelabelCnt}\pageref{pagelbl.\thelabelCnt}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}

        \lipsum[1-8]

        \insertCurrPgNum

        \lipsum[9-16]

        \insertCurrPgNum
    \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```